# Hyperbolic CORDIC in rotation (Z -> 0) to calculate sinh and cosh?

Tags: trigonometry, cordic, hyperbolic

I implemented both circular and hyperbolic CORDIC algorithm in rotation mode:`Z -> 0`

In case of `sin` and `cos` which using circular implementation, the results are accurate. In case of `sinh` and `cosh` which is the hyperbolic algorithm, they are not.

The output of the code below (`*_calc` is the CORDIC version, `*_good` is the math.* version) is the following:

```
sin_good(20): 0.3420201433256687
sin_calc(20): 0.34202014332566866

sinh_good(20): 242582597.70489514
sinh_calc(20): 0.3555015499407712

cos_good(20): 0.9396926207859084
cos_calc(20): 0.9396926207859082

cosh_good(20): 242582597.70489514
cosh_calc(20): 1.0594692478629741
```

What am I doing wrong?

```py
    def lookup_circular(iteration):
        return math.degrees(math.atan(2 ** -iteration))

    def lookup_linear(iteration):
        return 2 ** -iteration

    def lookup_hyperbolic(iteration):
        return math.degrees(math.atanh(2 ** -iteration))

    def sin(angle):
        x, y, z = cordic_circular_rotation_zto0(
            x=1 / circular_scaling_factor(),
            y=0,
            z=float(angle)
        )

        return y

    def cos(angle):
        x, y, z = cordic_circular_rotation_zto0(
            x=1 / circular_scaling_factor(),
            y=0,
            z=float(angle)
        )

        return x

    def sinh(angle):
        x, y, z = cordic_hyperbolic_rotation_zto0(
            x=1 / hyperbolic_scaling_factor(),
            y=0,
            z=angle
        )

        return y

    def cosh(angle):
        x, y, z = cordic_hyperbolic_rotation_zto0(
            x=1 / hyperbolic_scaling_factor(),
            y=0,
            z=angle
        )

        return x

    def cordic_circular_rotation_zto0(x, y, z, n=64):
        i = 0

        while i <= n:
            if z < 0:
                newx = x + (y * 2.0 ** (-i))
                newy = y - (x * 2.0 ** (-i))
                z = z + lookup_circular(i)
            else:
                newx = x - (y * 2.0 ** (-i))
                newy = y + (x * 2.0 ** (-i))
                z = z - lookup_circular(i)

            x = newx
            y = newy
            i += 1

        return x, y, z

    def cordic_hyperbolic_rotation_zto0(x, y, z, n=64):
        i = 1
        repeat = 4

        while i <= n:
            if z < 0:
                newx = x - (y * 2.0 ** (-i))
                newy = y - (x * 2.0 ** (-i))
                z = z + lookup_hyperbolic(i)
            else:
                newx = x + (y * 2.0 ** (-i))
                newy = y + (x * 2.0 ** (-i))
                z = z - lookup_hyperbolic(i)

            x = newx
            y = newy

            if i == repeat:
                repeat = (i * 3) + 1
            else:
                i += 1

        return x, y, z

    def circular_scaling_factor(n=64):
        e = 1

        for i in range(0, n):
            e = e * math.sqrt(1 + 2 ** (-2 * i))

        return e

    def hyperbolic_scaling_factor(n=64):
        e = 1

        for i in range(1, n):
            e = e * math.sqrt(1 - 2 ** (-2 * i))

        return e

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        angle = 20

        sin_res = sin(angle)
        print("sin_good({}): {}".format(angle, math.sin(math.radians(angle))))
        print("sin_calc({}): {}".format(angle, sin_res))

        print()
    
        sinh_res = sinh(angle)
        print("sinh_good({}): {}".format(angle, math.sinh(angle)))
        print("sinh_calc({}): {}".format(angle, sinh_res))
    
        print()

        cos_res = cos(angle)
        print("cos_good({}): {}".format(angle, math.cos(math.radians(angle))))
        print("cos_calc({}): {}".format(angle, cos_res))
    
        print()

        cosh_res = cosh(angle)
        print("cosh_good({}): {}".format(angle, math.cosh(angle)))
        print("cosh_calc({}): {}".format(angle, cosh_res))
```

Comment: Why do you convert your angles to radians for sin and cos, but not for sinh and cosh?

Comment: In the documentation of the math library, it says that the input of `sin` and `cos` are radians, on the other hand for hyperbolics it is not. Also, I would like to duplicate the way my scientific calculator works and the math library in the presented way gives the same results, 242582597 is the correct value.

Comment: Yes, I realised that. If you do (exp(20)-exp(-20))/2 you also get the same answer. Then, why do you convert to degrees for the inverse, math.atanh?

Answer (score 1):

By removing the `math.degrees` of the inverse hyperbolic tan of lookup_hyperbolic, I find the following result for cosh:

both functions match until x~1.1, and then the cordic function stays constant.
[image]

Which is what can be found in *Digital Arithmetic - Ercegovac/Lang 2003* [chapter 11](https://web.cs.ucla.edu/digital_arithmetic/viewgraphs_p.html)

> max angle = 1.11817

Same for sinh:

[image]

There is an extended cordic alogrithm that you could try to implement:

> Expanding the Range of Convergence of the CORDIC Algorithm
> X. Hu, R. Harber, S. Bass
> Published 1991
> Computer Science
> IEEE Trans. Computers